# Doubleclick in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, double-click

I have a problem with doubleclick event under IE 8. In different browser (FF, Chrome) everything works preety nice but in IE it works after 3 mouse clicks, not 2. Here is my code:

```
var DELAY = 250, clicks = 0, timer = null;
$(".selectable").click(function(e) {    

    if (timer == null) {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
           clicks = 0;
            timer = null;
            onNameClicked(e);
        }, DELAY);
    }


    if(clicks === 1) {  //here is problem, in IE is not into this if after doubleclick
         clearTimeout(timer);
         timer = null;
         clicks = -1;

        .
        .
        .
        }
      clicks++;  });
```

I know is an IE bug. How to resolve it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I noticed that is a problem with setTimeout function. When script is waiting DELAY time the rest of code is blocking and there isn't any reaction on clicking.

Comment: Ok I solved this issue. I handled doubleclick using '$(".selectable").dblclick(function(e)' and it works in IE8.